# How to run AndroidTestCase tests from Eclipse in a Maven project

Tags: android, maven, junit, m2e

I have an Android Maven project (using android-maven-plugin) with a project and a test project.

I configured Maven to run the instrumentation tests and they are running without a problem from maven (mvn clean install).

However I'm unable to run the test from Eclipse.
My test project contains two type of classes. Ones who inherit from *AndroidTestCase* and other that inherit from *ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2*

The test classes (in the test project) are build to *target/classes*.

I'm trying to run them as *Android JUnit test* but getting: **Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.RuntimeException'**

I saw [Simple non-API Android JUnit test in Eclipse with android-maven-plugin? thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593842/simple-non-api-android-junit-test-in-eclipse-with-android-maven-plugin/17136833#17136833)  And it seems that the issue is caused by [this bug](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/154) (The runner is expecting the classes to be under bin/classes which they are not).

On the other hand, There is a work around of running the tests by doing run as regular JUnit test and adding the classes to the classpath. This solution did not work either. I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:6)
    at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.getTest(JUnit3TestLoader.java:    102)
    at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit3TestLoader.jav    a:59)
    at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Is there any way to be able to run test project from both Maven and Eclipse?

Comment: Are you running these tests using the Eclipse or ADT JUnit launcher?

Comment: ADT launcher,  though I also tried Eclipse.

Comment: That exception looks as though you're running your tests locally against the SDK Android.jar which only contains Stubs of the Android API code.

Comment: The first error sounds like a bug in m2e-android. Not sure how to fix this. You might want to report it here: https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues

Comment: Done, [https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/189]

Comment: Which folder are you putting your instrumentation tests into? In the src/main/java folder in a separate test project? Or in src/test/java in the same project as your production code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Android Instrumentation tests with Maven inside the Eclipse emulator you MUST:

1. Run them in separate, integration test project/module.
2. Put the tests into a NON-TEST source folder like `src/main/java`.

Please see the [Maven Android Plugin Samples project](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/tree/master/apidemos-android-16) for an example.

Comment: It seems that you are correct. The problem originated from a wrong directory structure. After following the suggested convention I was able to run tests from both CLI (Using mvn clean install) and from Eclipse. Thank you for your support.